# `outputscript | gzip > $file` not overwriting $file

Tags: linux, centos, bash, gzip

I have an hourly cron script which take some output (a mysql dump), pipes it through gzip, and *aims* to overwrite a file of the same name. When I run it manually as `root` the file is overwritten. When it is ran by the cron daemon the filename has ".1" appended to it. This keeps happening so that after a while I have lots of files like so:

```
myfile.gz
myfile.gz.1
myfile.gz.1.1
myfile.gz.1.1.1
myfile.gz.1.1.1.1
```

and so on.

`ps aux|grep crond` shows that the daemon is being run as `root`.

I've tried:

- renaming the original file, pushing the output, then removing the old file on completion, and
- deleting the original file before piping the output

but neither works as expected and I just get `.1.1.1.1` files.

Script looks like this (nothing special) and is located on a CentOS box in `/etc/cron.hourly`:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=`date +%H`
DIR="/abs/path/to/dir"
FILE="hourly-${DATE}.gz"
OPTS="..."
mysqldump $OPTS | gzip -9 > $DIR/$FILE
```

Can anyone advise as to why this simple operation isn't running as expected?

Comment: If you want us to help you, you need to post the complete script.

Comment: It might also be helpful to show your crontab.

Comment: Is this your server?  This behaviour is very weird; it almost looks like someone has compiled a custom bash for it.

Comment: @ Zac - yes, this is my own server though I didn't build it I've been using it for the past 3 years without any issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, your script is written to use Bash features, but it's being run by the Bourne shell. Do you have `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of your script? Please post it so we can better help you.

**Edit**:

In scripts that are meant to run as cron jobs, I always specify the full path to programs (such as `mysqldump` and `gzip`) since the $PATH variable and things like aliases are going to be different from those in your interactive shell. That way, the results are predictable.

Comment: Yes; added script to question.

Comment: Looks like it was the absolute paths to the programs. Setting them fixed the problem instantly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this line to the top of your script after the bash line

```
set +C
```

This will turn off the noclobber option in bash so should overwrite the file.

If it's not that, then it's probably something like an alias to gzip being set either by cron or your overall environment.

Comment: An alias could not do this. The script has the redirect '>' command right in the command; it will be parsed by the shell before it gets to the gzip command.

Comment: I assume you're talking about this line?

mysqldump $OPTS | gzip -9 > $DIR/$FILE

If it's an alias, the gzip command could be anything at all, and might not even be producing anything on STDOUT to be redirected, making the > redundant?

It would be odd, but then this issue is pretty odd

Answer (score 1):

That seems really strange to me, bash has a noclobber option that makes it so redirection will not overwrite a file.  Maybe this a recent version a new option that is similar, but creates a .1 file instead?

Is it possible something like logrotate is called in the cronjob, or something runs right before it that moves the file (logrotate)?  You should check /etc/crontab and `crontab -e` run as root.

Is this on some sort of cloud or shared hosting site?  Maybe the provider has created something that does this to help reduce their ticket load :-)

Comment: My dump script is the only script that runs hourly, so I don't think it could be logrotate.

Comment: gzip is an alias that moves the file first? Or there is a gzip in the path that moves a file first, but I don't really even so how that would work ...

Answer (score 1):

Try to set 
`#!/bin/bash -x` a
nd write /path/to/bash_script 1 > /path/to/log_file
(where in /path/... set your own path to files).

Answer (score 0):

It's not `gzip -c`? That option is for writing to stdout rather than to a file. Is there a `GZIP` or `GZIP_OPT` environment variable set (with gzip options in it)?

Comment: `gzip` in a pipe doesn't need `-c`

Comment: looks to be working fine without the `-c` option.